# Only some Converters fire?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, ivalueconverter

I am working on a project in WPF and I have a very strange case concerning my converters on a certain element.

In the following snippet:

```
<myCtl:Pager IsTabStop="False" Style="{StaticResource MainPager}"
                DataContext="{Binding CurrentView, Converter={StaticResource SectionToPagerDriver}}"
                Visibility="{Binding CurrentView, Converter={StaticResource SectionToVisibility}}"/>
```

The converter for 'DataContext' will fire, but the converter for 'Visibility' will not.  This seems odd to me considering that they are both bound to 'CurrentView' which indeed changes.  I have even tried setting the binding mode explicitly to 'TwoWay' but this does nothing to resolve the issue.

Does anyone have a clue why one binding would fire, and the other would not ?

Comment: if you comment out the `DataContext` part : `DataContext="{Binding CurrentView, Converter={StaticResource SectionToPagerDriver}}"`, will `SectionToVisibility` fire?

Comment: Set this to high http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources.tracelevel.aspx and test

Comment: @Bolu No. On its own it won't even fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the `DataContext` on your `Control`, all other bindings will use the new object as their source.

If you check your output window, you'll see a binding error saying that there is no `CurrentView` property on whatever object is returned by that property.

Instead, you should just do:

```
<myCtl:Pager IsTabStop="False" Style="{StaticResource MainPager}"
             DataContext="{Binding CurrentView, Converter={StaticResource SectionToPagerDriver}}"
             Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource SectionToVisibility}}"/>
```

Comment: You are half right.  By removing 'CurrentView' I get the correct behaviour, but there is no Binding error reported in the original case. (otherwise I would have figured it out)

Comment: That is odd. Maybe it is because the `Binding` is valid before the `DataContext` changes.